# Divide bootstrap row into 13 parts with small margin on left/right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create a responsive, centered deck of cards, where there will be 13 cards in a row, with a small margins at left and at right edges of the page. How could I make it?

Comment: Create your own baker-dozen based CSS classes similar to bootstrap's dozen.  
I think the question is a joke.

Comment: @AlexanderKudryashev nothing wrong with the question. your comment looks more over like a joke.

Comment: Nothing about joke. Follow bootstrap practice. They created css classes based 1/12 width. Build your custom css based on 1/13 width.

Comment: Why build your own and mess up stuffs when bootstrap already have given you the flexibility to customize it while downloading... @AlexanderKudryashev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to customize this requirement before downloading your bootstrap package in bootstrap website itself**

In the **[bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/)** you have link called **[Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)** . This section is to customize your bootstrap framework to the way you like and download the customized version. There are many stuff to customize here.

Coming to your question.

> Divide bootstrap row into 13 parts

In the Customize page navigate to the **[Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)** and here you can find that the default `@grid-columns` is set to 12, **Change it to 13**

[image]

Comment: @Michal_Szulc glad this helped you.. happy coding!!